# Benefits of making variables local as opposed to global

Tags: java, variables, global-variables, local-variables

In my current program, I have some variables declared at the start such as:

```
private static final double imageSize
```

This variable is not changed and only used in a single method so my IDE is telling me to make it a local variable. What are the benefits of this? I change the variable regularly when test so is it okay to keep it where it is?

Comment: Where is it initialised? Can you make it `final`?

Comment: It is final, sorry I forgot to add that. It is currently initialized when you create the class, outside of the class's main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically it is okay to let it be where it is. Moreover, as you are changing the value yourself, it makes it more readable keeping it at the top.

The IDE is suggesting to keep it local to the method because it is recommended practice to keep visibility and lifetime of a variable to the minimum possible scope. By leaving it at class level, your variable lives as long as the class is loaded, even though the method using it ended its execution.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable has only one benefit: when you're coding this viarable od disponsable only to this local code (for example method).
When you have a big project and 100 variables is very usefull to have local variables.
But in your case: it is better to have global static variables assigned to things that do not change in the program.  When you need to, you'll be able to easily find this variable.  for example in 5 years the monitors will have 10 meters and you will want to change the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to answer Jacek. Your variable look like constant.
According to the [Java code convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) for constant variables (**final**) you should use upper case:

```
private static final double IMAGE_SIZE
```